# does visual studio have anything that shows snippets of code for the Windows API(like I think VB6 might have)?

Tags: visual-studio

does visual studio have anything that shows snippets of code for  the Windows API(like I think VB6 might have)?

For example you'd select an API function and it showed a code snippet.. i recall something like that from the VB6 days.  It made it easier to test out any API function because it showed some example code to declare it and possibly even to use it.

Comment: No.  [This website](http://pinvoke.net/) might be useful, but the question isn't specific enough to know why you need this.

Comment: @HansPassant ok i just edited my q to be more clear why I need it, also i posted an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if VB6 had, but there was a program called ApiViewer that did that [image]

And there is currently a comparable program

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92967/VB-9-0-C-3-0-API-Viewer

[image]

that uses a website called pinvoke.net

And there is an addin to visual studio from the  team that did the pinvoke.net website

http://pinvoke.net/

[image]

Comment: there is  a program called winspector mentioned https://improve.dk/the-basics/ maybe used by autohotkey people as well as visual studio people